# C++ use Assert::AreEqual string and string

Tags: c++, visual-studio, char, wchar-t, microsoft-unit-testing

I use the Microsoft Unit Testing for C++, but when I use Assert::AreEqual comparing string and the string contains Chinese words. The Test Explorer display unrecognizable characters.

```
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace tests
{
    using std::string,std::wstring;
    TEST_CLASS(Test)
    {
    public:
        TEST_METHOD(test)
        {
            Assert::AreEqual("测试", "测试1");
        }
    };
}
```

[unrecognizable characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTeiB.png)

If I should use converter to change the string or char* to wstring or wcahr_t*?

```
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace tests
{
    using std::string,std::wstring;
    TEST_CLASS(Test)
    {
    public:
        TEST_METHOD(test)
        {
            Assert::AreEqual(L"测试", L"测试1");
        }
    };
}
```

[recognizable characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8LtI.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fails to display the correct character set but does not affect the results.

For displaying Chinese, you need to use wide characters.

Comment: That said, normally I don't need to change my original working code, and if I want to display it properly in my tests, is it better to convert to wide characters or wait for Microsoft to improve this detail someday?

Comment: You can submit a report to [Visual Studio Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp). But currently it is better to use wide characters.